# Ubuntu Repositories on Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository, addition, apt

I'm was trying to add Ubuntu repository on Debian, but get an error:

`Err:11 https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu focal InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C`

How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately, this is not a programming question in the sense of SO's policies. You would be better off asking this on unix.stackexchange.com or similar sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theoretically you can import the missing GPG key to Debian but it is a bad idea.
to import the missing keys to Debian you must go:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
```

normally you should check out there always is the same package also in a Debian repository.
Best solution is to add the right Debian repositories.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian, fix problem:

```
 the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 NO_PUBKEY    
 871920D1991BC93C
```

Try the below code:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring

sudo apt-key update

sudo apt-get update
```